# cross language framework like axon framework?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Is there a cross language framework like axon framework?
I need a cross language DDD framework supporting Java, .Net, nodejs, golang

There are multiple development languages in my company,I expect to implement DDD without changing the programming language used by developers

I expect a cross language development framework

Answer (score 0):

The greater part of the value of DDD comes from the strategic patterns, which are non-technical. Take a look at this video for an overview: [Strategic Domain-Driven Design by Nick Tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNW8bdTw_IU)

Then on the technical side, your domain code can remain pretty framework free and using hexagonal/ports and adapters/clean architecture whatever framework is most mature/productive can be used for the implementation of repositories/services/APIs/busses etc.

That being said, [DAPR](https://dapr.io/) is the 1st cross-language framework I have seen (that is less intrusive than Service Fabric) that ticks a lot of the boxes. I will say it is still early in development and I have not used it in any meaningful way myself.

Comment: I forgot to mention that DAPR is not specifically written for DDD like Vlingo, it just encompasses a few things that are common to most projects and supports multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to satisfying this requirement is to use a service oriented/microservices architecture.

Essentially, you would be exposing all of your domain behavior via a set of interfaces that are implemented via REST-ish apis. What that means is that the implementer of a service can create their service in any language independent of what the clients of the service are using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like Akka Serverless from Lightbend would fit the bill: business logic can be implemented in any language which supports gRPC.